# SapUI5 - Add own data to a Tile?

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to build a sample application which will display data from a json file. For this I want to use Tiles to display each item in the json file. That is my json file contains the following data:

```
{
"items":[
       {
           "id": "item1",
           "des": "All kind of books!",
           "content": "These deals are too big to be public, save 50% or more on your hotel booking!",
           "pname": "BOOKS",
           "to": "ui5consumption@sap.com",
           "price": "Flat 50% off!",
           "unread": true,
           "important": true
       },
       {
           "id": "item2",
           "des": "Branded!",
           "content": "Deal of the day. Recommended deals: unbelievable discount!",
           "pname": "WALLETS",
           "to": "ui5consumption@sap.com",
           "price": "Upto 50% off!",
           "unread": true,
           "important": false
       },
       {
           "id": "item3",
           "des": "By most famous authors!",
           "content": "Dear ui5consumption, below you can find the postings which match the agents configured by you.",
           "pname": "NOVELS",
           "to": "ui5consumption@sap.com",
           "price": "Flat 50% off!",
           "unread": true,
           "important": true
       },
       {
           "id": "item1",
           "des": "+DVDs+Dual DVDs",
           "content": "These deals are too big to be public, save 50% or more on your hotel booking!",
           "pname": "CDS",
           "to": "ui5consumption@sap.com",
           "price": "Between Rs.10-500/-",
           "unread": true,
           "important": true
       },
       {
           "id": "item1",
           "des": "Pen/Notebooks/ETC.",
           "content": "These deals are too big to be public, save 50% or more on your hotel booking!",
           "pname": "STATIONARY",
           "to": "ui5consumption@sap.com",
           "price": "Between Rs.05-5000/-",
           "unread": true,
           "important": true
       },
       {
           "id": "item1",
           "des": "All brands!",
           "content": "These deals are too big to be public, save 50% or more on your hotel booking!",
           "pname": "TVs",
           "to": "ui5consumption@sap.com",
           "price": "Upto 50% off!",
           "unread": true,
           "important": true
       },
       {
           "id": "item1",
           "des": "Fast food available here!",
           "content": "These deals are too big to be public, save 50% or more on your hotel booking!",
           "pname": "EATABLES",
           "to": "ui5consumption@sap.com",
           "price": "Between Rs.10-500/-",
           "unread": true,
           "important": true
       }
]
```

}

Now I want the data in each item(i.e., id, des, pname, etc..) to be displayed in separate tiles. How do I achieve that? Please help. I an new to SapUI5.

Comment: Hi, what have you already tried yourself? Have you looked at the CustomTile control? It can contain anything you want

Comment: @Qualiture This is my tile container: <TileContainer
      id="container"
      tileDelete="handleTileDelete"
      tiles="{/items}">
      <CustomTile>
       
      </CustomTile>
      
    </TileContainer>   But I don't know exactly how to place and display data here. Can you give me an example?

Comment: As you can see in the API at https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.CustomTile.html, the `content` aggregation takes any `sap.ui.core.Control`. In your case, I would simply create a MatrixLayout, Grid or Form to display the needed content, and add that to the content aggregation